# dnn linqtosql Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, dotnetnuke

I have such a code that tries to save some informations to database but my datacontext cannot be created. And it gives such an exception "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**."     When i debugged,  it jumps form "DataContext1 db = new DataContext1();" line to catch block and gives that exception. Is there any solution to this?

```
public class AuthorPaperDetails
{
    public void SaveAuthorPaperDetails(string pTitle, string confMakerId, 
                                                string additionalPaperTitle,string mainAuthor, 
                                                int regFeeForFirstAuthor,int regFeeForAdditionalPaper, int RegFeeForCoAuthors)
    {

        try
        {
            DataContext1 db = new DataContext1();
            AuthorPaperDetail authorPaperDetail = new AuthorPaperDetail();

            authorPaperDetail.paper_title = pTitle;
            authorPaperDetail.conference_maker_id = confMakerId;
            authorPaperDetail.additional_paper_title = additionalPaperTitle;
            authorPaperDetail.areYouMainAuthor = mainAuthor;
            authorPaperDetail.feeForFirstAuthorPaper = regFeeForFirstAuthor;
            authorPaperDetail.feeForAdditionalPaper = regFeeForAdditionalPaper;
            authorPaperDetail.feeForParticipCoAuthors = RegFeeForCoAuthors;

            db.AuthorPaperDetails.InsertOnSubmit(authorPaperDetail);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you not save the connection information when you created the dbml or do you need to pass the connection information into the DataContext like so:

```
TestDataContext dc = new TestDataContext("ConnectionString1");
```

Comment: I tried it but now it gives such an exception "**Invalid operation. The connection is closed.**"

Comment: As long as the connection string you are passing is valid (if you can send a mocked up version I can take a look) then the call should be open.  I typically use a using statement on the datacontext creation using(TestDataContext dc = new TestDataContext("ConnectionString1")){...} I would need a stack trace or something more to help out.

Comment: you should write whole connection string instead of the connection string name as a parameter.

Comment: Than you  user1125188, for your help. This solution solved my problem. And as ersan said, I used whole connection string name to solve problem.